# Alamofire how to parse JSON in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I used Alamofire's GET function to return this JSON from API.
Here's how I used Alamofire:

```
struct Params: Encodable {
            let code: String
            let codeType: String
        }

        let params = Params(code: "709532929804933", codeType: "IDENTCODE")
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Authorization": "Basic xxxHIDExxx",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        ]
        
        AF.request("https://xxx.xx/cloudcrm/customer",
                   method: .get,
                   parameters: params,
                   headers: headers).validate(statusCode: 200..<300).responseJSON { response in
                    switch response.result {
                            case .success:
                                debugPrint(response.value as Any)
                         
                    case let .failure(error): 
                                print(error)
                            }
                   }

        
Print json:
{
    customerData = "<zakaznik><zkznid>475301</zkznid><titul></titul><jmeno>757B746D</jmeno><prijmeni>D\U00c1RKOV\U00c1 KARTA</prijmeni><rozliseni></rozliseni><osloveniok>false</osloveniok><kontos></kontos><skupzak1_klic>DK</skupzak1_klic><skupzak2_klic>default</skupzak2_klic><cenkat_klic>1</cenkat_klic><platido>2118-07-31</platido><valid>true</valid></zakaznik>";
    message = "Informace o z\U00e1kazn\U00edkovi \"D\U00c1RKOV\U00c1 KARTA 757B746D\" na\U010dteny.";
}
```

I tried to see if the JSON is valid (https://jsonlint.com/), but it's not.
Is there any way to parse this string in Swift?

Comment: It's JSON, and `response.value` is a `<String: Any>`, and use OpenStep format to print it. Use `Codable` instead of `responseJSON`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's JSON.
It has already been parsed and `response.value` is a `Dictionary`, a `[String: Any]`, and in your sample case, even a `[String: String]`.
What you printed is the `description` of a `NSDictionary` (more or less a Swift Dictionary), and the output is in OpenStep Format.
Notice the: `"="` between key & value, and the ";" at the end of the line.
What tells me that's also JSON? You printed it in the `success` case, so it succeed parsing the Data into "JSON" object.

If you want to see the actual "JSON" data you received:

```
let responseStr = String(data: response.data!, encoding: .utf8)
print("Received: \(responseStr)")
```

You should see it's valid JSON.

Now, `responseJSON` is deprecated, please use `Codable` and `responseDecodable(of:)`.

If you still don't want to use `Codable`:

```
if let dict = response.value as? [String: Any] {
    if let customerData = dict["customerData"] as? String {
        print("customerData: \(customerData)")
        //Parse the XML
    }
    if let message = dict["message"] as? String {
        print("message: \(message)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Larme
And if I want to get only <zkznid> value from customerData?

Comment: You have XML, use a XML parser, or maybe just a regex, but that's another question.